# I am not receiving an email from a Anypoint Cloudhub Alert

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, alerts, cloudhub

I have set up a custom alert in Anypoint Cloudhub to raise the alert if the application encounters a mongodb error.  I am seeing the error but am not receiving an email.

I am down as the recipient and have the alert turned on but I cannot see an alert (which I think should be an email).

I'm using Mule 3.8.3 in Runtime Manager.

**Alert:**
[image]

**Error in log:**

```
********************************************************************************
18:27:45.629     02/27/2017     Worker-0     [test].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01     ERROR

********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke findOneDocument.
Element               : /getRecord/processors/4 @ test
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Failed to invoke findOneDocument. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the CloudHub connector to generate the custom alert notification? Are you sure the alert contains com.mongodb? Also, are you sure you set a valid email address for the notification? Are you also seeing the Alert in Runtime Manager? Make sure you set a Anypoint Platform user as the alert recipient and that that user has permission to view alerts from this business-group/environment.